# DateDiff not available on Access 2013

Tags: date, expression, ms-access-2013, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am trying to use the so called DateDiff function to subtract the End Date from the Start Date and obtain the numbers of days apart.For example:
*10/11/1995* - *7/11/1995* = **3** (extract the 'dd' from DD/MM/YYYY format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As date values are double with the integer part counting for a day, you can use this simple expression:

```
[Due Date]-[Start Date]
```

or, for integer days only:

```
Fix([Due Date]-[Start Date])
```

That said, you should a query for tasks like this.

Comment: this works just fine, thanks! as for your other question, I'm afraid I don't know how to use expression builder to filter on 2 conditions. thanks

Comment: Create one condition and check. Not the syntax. Delete this and create the other condition. Note the syntax and combine this with an `And` the first condition.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it says it cannot find the name 'Task' you entered in the expression.`="[Task]=" & "'" & [Task] & "'" And "[Employee ID]=" & "'" & [Employee ID] & "'"` The first code works on a different form and filters the report by title (task). `="[Task]=" & "'" & [Title] & "'"`. The second code works on the existing form I'm working on and filters report by Employee ID. `="[Employee ID]=" & "'" & [Employee ID] & "'"`. However, when combined, it does not work. For the second part, the control source and the field filtered on the report both are called Task. Hope system's not confused.

Comment: If Task works on a different form, it is missing on this form or it would be found.